# simplepie include a php file with feed list

Tags: php, simplepie

I need a little help with simplepie and php. 
I use this code to echo a multifeed:

```
<?php
echo SimplePieWP(array(
    'http://feed1',
    'http://feed2',
    'http://feed3',
), array(
    'items' => 5,
));
?>
```

It works fine, but I want to have the feeds as a list in a different php file as below:

```
'http://feed1',
'http://feed2',
'http://feed3',
```

How should I modify the first code to include the php file with the feed array? I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<?php
echo SimplePieWP(array(
    include("feed_array.php");
), array(
    'items' => 5,
));
?>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost, you can have includes return a value as well:

```
#feed_array.php
<?php
  return [
    'http://feed1',
    'http://feed2',
    'http://feed3'
  ];
?>

#index.php
<?php
  echo SimplePieWP(include('feed_array.php'),[
    'items' => 5
  ]);
?>
```

But keep in mind that if the include fails, it throws a warning *and* returns `false` instead.

Comment: do a `var_dump(include('feed_array.php'))` if its a `bool`, the include failed.

Comment: unfortunately no improvement

Comment: What is the output of that statement?

Comment: Then either you didn't implement it as the code above or you're running a PHP version < 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132339/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-merxie).

Comment: the file is in the same folder as the simplepie. It should be picked up,  or no?